# Bluetooth turning on by itself

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a Toshiba Satellite L640 laptop, running Windows 7 32-bit. Whenever I turn off Bluetooth (using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> shortcut), it stays off for only a few seconds, then turns on again. How can I resolve this?

Bluetooth-related software on the laptop:

- SL640_Win7_Bluetooth_Stack_for_Windows_by_Toshiba_v7.10.09
- SL640_Win7_Bluetooth_Monitor_v4.04

Comment: How *exactly* are you turning bluetooth off? And how did you establish that it was active again?

Comment: I turned on and off using FN + F8. There are details about the wifi and bluetooth, so I can know that the bluetooth is switched on or off

Comment: @RhienaRava - Have you ever synced the a bluetooth device to your computer?  My guess there is a problem with the shortcut.  Disable the device through windows not the shortcut.

Comment: look into all applications and peripherals that use bluetooth to communicate, one of them is most probably switching it on again

Answer (score 0):

you must try too reinstalling the bluetooth driver first,